# Struggling very much to turn the format of a dataframe from strings to floats

Tags: pandas

I have this df which I got from using the `read_html` property :

```
              0      1         2        3 

1             AB   16.38   16197.69  19/05
2             AC   81.48    4671.23  19/05
3             AR   12.10    3329.37  19/05
4             AS   35.69   11178.46  19/05
```

The second and third columns are numbers however they are recorgnised as str.

I would like to turn them into floats because on the third column I would like to carry out a division of each of the values of column `2` by its total.

The desired output would be something like this:

```
     0          1         2       3 

1   AB      16.38    0.457    19/05
2   AC      81.48    0.132    19/05
3   AR      12.10    0.094    19/05
4   AS      35.69    0.315    19/05
```

This is what I have tried:

On one side stating the decimals and thousands

```
pd.read_html('http:// whatever', flavor='html5lib', thousands='.',decimal=',')
```

on the other side changing the format of the df to `numeric`

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

When I print the desired formula over the column :

```
df.loc[:,2]/df.loc[:,2].sum())
```

The following error appears :

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Just would like to change the format of the column to apply above operation.

Comment: Just a guess, but you are using `decimal=','` whereas your data clearly uses a dot as decimal sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you  need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for convert non numeric to `NaN`:

```
df[1] = pd.to_numeric(df[1], errors='coerce')
df[2] = pd.to_numeric(df[2], errors='coerce')
```

But first you can check which values are not parsed by:

```
print (df[pd.to_numeric(df[1], errors='coerce').isnull()])

print (df[pd.to_numeric(df[2], errors='coerce').isnull()])
```

Comment: Always great  @jezrael